# attempting to replace all alphabetical characters except a specific pattern with regEXP

Tags: json, dart

Hello guys I am looking to take a string gathered from json output sent through a parametized query. The output will be:

```
{"id":"2","firstName":"Jim","lastName":"Fuller"},
{"id":"3","firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Vasquez"}]
```

As a full string of course. I used the first RegExp to replace to replace all special characters.

The second RegExp removes all special characters and keeps then new line. So far the output looks like this:

```
1firstNameJimlastNameFuller
2firstNameJoelastNameVasquez
```

After running the last RegExp replace, it removes all alphanumeric characters but it also removes the new line. I want to keep the new line.

output: 12

How can I make the third RegExp remove characters and not a new line?

```
data = data.replaceAll(RegExp('[^A-Za-z0-9]'), '');
data = data.replaceAll(RegExp('id'), '\n');
data = data.replaceAll(RegExp('[\\D.]'),'');
```

Comment: Haven't tested, but I think on that third one, you want to keep only the digits and a newline, so to invert that, it's `[^\n\d]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negated character class that lists all the chars you want to *keep*:

```
data = data.replaceAll(RegExp('[^\\d\n\r]'),'');
```